# Populate a custom ListView item with JSOUP

Tags: android, listview, jsoup

This is a part of my Fragment, which extracts some parts of a HTML table:

```
public class Vertretung extends Fragment {
        ArrayList<Vertretungsdaten> mData = new ArrayList<Vertretungsdaten>();
        ListView mListView;
        private CustomAdapter mAdapter;
                 //unrelevant stuff
            String URL = "https://greselius.net/idesk/vplan/Anzeige/Schueler_heute/subst_001.htm";
            try {
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect(URL).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X; de-de) AppleWebKit/523.10.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0.4 Safari/523.10").get(
                );
                Elements questions = doc.select("table.mon_list");
                Elements td = questions.select("td[align]");
                for (Element myElement: td) {
                    Vertretungsdaten daten = new Vertretungsdaten();
                    daten.setKlasse(myElement.text());
                    daten.setStunde(myElement.text());
                    daten.setVertreter(myElement.text());
                    daten.setFach(myElement.text());
                    daten.setRaum(myElement.text());
                    daten.setLehrer(myElement.text());
                    daten.setArt(myElement.text());
                    daten.setText(myElement.text());
                    mData.add(daten);
                }
```

This is my `Vertretungsdaten` class:

```
public class Vertretungsdaten {
    private String klasse;
    private String stunde;
    private String vertreter;
    private String fach;
    private String raum;
    private String lehrer;
    private String art;
    private String text;
    private int typ;

    public Vertretungsdaten() {

    }


    public String getVertreter() {
        return vertreter;
    }

    public void setVertreter(String vertreter) {
        this.vertreter = vertreter;
    }
```

There are getters and setters for every string.
Now this is my CustomAdapter:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Vertretungsdaten> {

    private ArrayList<Vertretungsdaten> objects;


    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Vertretungsdaten> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        this.objects = objects;
    }


    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        View v = convertView;


        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);
        }


        Vertretungsdaten i = objects.get(position);

        if (i != null) {

            TextView lehrer = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.lehrer);
            //same thing for the other textviews

            lehrer.setText(i.getLehrer());
            //again same thing for the other textviews

        return v;

    }

}
```

Now I have an custom listview, which should be populated like this:

```
Klasse      Lehrer       Fach       Art
Stunde      Vertreter    Raum       Text

Klasse      Lehrer       Fach       Art
Stunde      Vertreter    Raum       Text

Klasse      Lehrer       Fach       Art
Stunde      Vertreter    Raum       Text
```

But what happens is:

```
Klasse      Klasse       Klasse     Klasse
Klasse      Klasse       Klasse     Klasse

Stunde      Stunde       Stunde     Stunde
Stunde      Stunde       Stunde     Stunde
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the array that you are building:

```
for (Element final : td) {
                        Vertretungsdaten daten = new Vertretungsdaten();
                        daten.setKlasse(question.text());
                        daten.setStunde(question.text());
                        daten.setVertreter(question.text());
                        daten.setFach(question.text());
                        daten.setRaum(question.text());
                        daten.setLehrer(question.text());
                        daten.setArt(question.text());
                        daten.setText(question.text());
                        mData.add(daten);
                    }
```

You are using the same object "question" in the loop. Can you show where it is initialized? and "td" too?you should use "final", final.text() to populate daten.
(Also using the word "final" is not good to use for a variable.)

```
for (Element myElement: td) {
                        Vertretungsdaten daten = new Vertretungsdaten();
                        daten.setKlasse(myElement.text());
                        daten.setStunde(myElement.text());
                        daten.setVertreter(myElement.text());
                        daten.setFach(myElement.text());
                        daten.setRaum(myElement.text());
                        daten.setLehrer(myElement.text());
                        daten.setArt(myElement.text());
                        daten.setText(myElement.text());
                        mData.add(daten);
                    }
```

try to put some logs in the loop to see what you add in mData.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to replace question with final, but this doesn't fix my problem. I edited my post so you can see where td gets initialized.